# Multi user/site rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a web app where people will sign up, call it main-app.com, when they sign up my code will generate a usersite.my-app.com, they will login and only be able to manage their mini site. My question is, is it correct to model this out by creating a table for site, a table for user, users belong to site and site has many users. Then I should create a content table that belongs to user AND site?

Is that right?

Comment: You have the right approach, Jeff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on this for one of my apps at the moment using the Devise authentication plugin.

To get the central user environment, I was simply going to shard the database using Octopus, Connection_ninja. All are on Github

It's a starting point but not the full solution I'm afraid as I haven't got there myself yet.  There are going to be issues to consider such as determining authorization of app specific resources based on which site the user has registered.

Alternatively, The latest edition of Ruby Weekly links to an interesting article on a Ruby implimentation of the Central Authentication Service protocol.  It will be worth a read - http://blog.econify.com/2010/12/introducing-classycas.html

Hope this helps a bit...